# Is ugarchfit / ugarchforecast non-deterministic?

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I've been playing around a bit with fitting an ARIMA-GARCH model to S&P 500 historical data from 2005 until the end of 2008. The code is largely based on the book 'Advanced Algorithmic Trading' by Mike Halls-Moore. The idea is straightforward. We first fit an arma model to the log returns of the 500 previous days and chooses the best parameters p, q. These parameters are given as an input to the GARCH model, using ugarchfit() from the 'rugarch' library. Predictions are then made by using ugarchforecast().

The problem I am encountering is that running the same code twice in a row produces different forecasts for about 3% of the days. This is the code that I am using:

```
# Import libraries
library(quantmod)
library(lattice)
library(timeSeries)
library(rugarch)

# Get the S&P 500 data
getSymbols("^GSPC", from="2003-01-01")
spReturns = diff(log(Cl(GSPC["2003-01-01/2009"])))
spReturns[as.character(head(index(Cl(GSPC["2003-01-01/2009"])),1))] = 0

# Create a vector of the forecasts
windowLength = 500 # The rolling window used to make the predictions
foreLength = length(spReturns) - windowLength
forecasts <- vector(mode="character", length=1)

# r stands for the rolling window
for (r in 0:foreLength) {
  # We first select the best ARMA model based on the previous days
  spReturnsOffset = spReturns[(1+r):(windowLength+r)]
  final.aic <- Inf
  final.order <- c(0,0,0)
  for (p in 0:5) for (q in 0:5) {
    if (p==0 && q==0) {next}
    arimaFit = tryCatch(arima(spReturnsOffset, order=c(p, 0, q)), error=function(err) FALSE, warning=function(err) FALSE)
    if(!is.logical(arimaFit)) { 
      current.aic <- AIC(arimaFit) 
      if (current.aic < final.aic) {
        final.aic <- current.aic
        final.order <- c(p, 0, q)
        final.arima <- arimaFit
      }
    } else {next}
  }

  # We now do the ARMA-GARCH fitting, where we pass the best ARMA order found above
  spec = ugarchspec(variance.model=list(garchOrder=c(1,1)), mean.model=list(armaOrder=c(final.order[1],final.order[3]),include.mean=T), distribution.model="sged")
  fit = tryCatch(ugarchfit(spec, spReturnsOffset, solver='hybrid'), error=function(e) e, warning=function(w) w)
  # If the fit does not converge, take 0 as our forecast
  if(is(fit, "warning")) {forecasts[r+1] = 0} 
  else {
    fore = ugarchforecast(fit, n.ahead=1)
    forecasts[r+1] = fore@forecast$seriesFor[1]
    }
}
```

I ran the code twice in a row and it turned out that a few of the values in the forecasts vector were different between the two runs. In particular, I noticed the following:

1. The ARMA model gave the same parameters (p, q, AIC) for all points of both runs.
2. In run 1, the GARCH model produced 32 warnings, in run 2 it produced 41 warnings. Many of these warnings occurred at the same data points, however there were a total of 19 warnings that only occurred in either one of the runs.
3. Obviously, the forecasts at these 19 data points differed between the two runs. However, there were 10 more data points that produced different forecasts. So in total, there were 29 out of 1000 forecasts that differed between the two runs.
4. There were 2 days in run 1 and 4 days in run 2, at which the forecast values were >5 (all other values are <0.02). Curiously, at 5 out of 6 of these abnormal predictions there was a warning in the other run (for example a prediction >5 in run 1 but a warning and therefore no prediction in run 2).
5. Randomly, maybe at every 1 out of 2000 data points, I get an error message: 'Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors' which stops the execution of the code.

All of this behaviour is quite puzzling to me. Shouldn't the same input parameters always lead to the same results/errors? Is there some random seed being used in ugarchfit?

Could it eventually be due to the solver='hybrid' parameter in ugarchfit? But then again I'm not sure what other solver to use here and the documentation is very vague on this.